# Apache Ignite .NET Client Near Cache

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

Is there a way to configure near cache for a thin client?

It appears that this API is missing from .NET NuGet package.  Here is sample code:

```
var ignite = Ignition.StartClient(cfg);
var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<string, string>( "mycache");
```

`GetOrCreateCache` seems to be missing an overload that takes near cache configuration...  Is this something that is simply not developed yet?

Answer (score 3):

No, thin clients doesn't support near caches.

For your case you should use thick client and configure near cache as described here:
https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/near-caches